# In a 7x7 grid, what is the number in the bottom right corner?

Tags: analysis, pattern-recognition

My math teacher have presented me with a problem, that in my opinion is quite hard. It goes.

"You have a 7x7 grid. Some of the spaces in the grid are already filled with numbers. You have to insert numbers in the remaining spaces, so that the sum in every 3x3 grid inside the 7x7, is 2019. What number should be in the bottom right corner?"
[Here is the grid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s65A8.png)

I know the answer is 7, but I have no idea of how you arrive at that answer.

Comment: Hint: Fill in as many zeroes as you can, until you are forced to put a number to make the total sum of the grid $2019$.

Comment: Also, are you sure the number in the top right corner is correct?

Comment: Cool, I will try using that strategy. That picture came with the problem, so I must assume it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** fill in the sums in the boxes such that every 3x3 sub grid has the same sum.
\begin{array}{|ccccc|}
\hline
10 & \boxed{a+b} & 8 & \boxed{c+d} & 11 \\
\\
\\
7 & \boxed{\phantom{0\quad 0}} & \boxed{\phantom 0} & \boxed{\phantom{0\quad 0}} & \boxed{\phantom 0} \\
\\
\\
6 & \boxed{\phantom{0\quad 0}} & \boxed{\phantom 0} & \boxed{\phantom{0\quad 0}} & \boxed{\phantom 0} \\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: How would I know sum to start with? Should I for instance say a= 15 b=20, and then work  my way down?

Comment: You could do that. But I intended to leave them as is. So for instance the first empty rectangle must contain $a+b+10-7$ to ensure the 3x3 sub grid has the same sum.

Comment: Yeah okay now I see. But what should I then put inside the square next to the rectangle. Just an 8 as the square above it?

Comment: If we shift the top left square a row down, we lose $10+a+b$, and gain $7$ plus an unknown sum. Therefore that unknown sum must be $a+b+3$. If we shift the square with $a+b,8$ a row down, we lose $a+b+8$, and gain $a+b+3$ plus the unknown square. Therefore the unknown square must be $5$.